# Generalised inverses - Solve normal equations

Tags: self-study, least-squares, proof, matrix-inverse

I am still not fully able to handle the concept of generalised inverses when applied to OLS.

Is there a way to show that

$\beta$ = $\ (X'X)^- X'y + (I_k−(X'X)^-X'X)z $

solves the normal equations:

$\ X'X$$\beta$ =$\ X'y $ so that it holds for any z?

Note: $\ X $ is an (n × k)-regressor

Comment: I rolled back the attempted edit by another user because they did not recognize the special--and crucial--meaning attached to the superscript minus sign: of course, it refers to the [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse).  This particular question is explicitly addressed at [the end of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse#Uses).

Comment: Thanks you! Yes, it was changed in another task as well and I was blamed for it. Sorry.

Comment: +1 because I just realised the notational difference, my initial reaction was: "Hey the Moore-Penrose pseudo-invereis with the $+$" and then went like... "Oh... the $-$... forgot all about that!"